# Performing a statistical analysis on how 'similar' two sets of particles are moving

Tags: time-series, correlation, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, modeling

A bunch of N particles are moving in a 2D plane. We are able to get their positions, speeds, and directions of moving at any given time.

Another bunch of M particles, somewhere 'beside' the N particles, also have their positions, speeds, and directions recorded.

If the first N particles move, the M particles somewhat move "similarly" at a later time, trying to 'mimic' or follow the first N particles.

Using their positions, velocities, I want to study how similar these movements are. If the M particles eventually trace the path or follow the motion of the first N particles.

What statistical concept am I looking at here? Cross-correlation? Your insights would be indeed helpful.

Comment: Could you tell us some context? What are this "particles" in real life? Show us some plots? ... Maybe 1) Kalman filter? 2) [Procrustes analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55405/looking-for-a-test-for-shape-comparison)? ...